# ack-grep: command not found after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: grep

```
sudo apt-get install ack-grep
```

gives

```
ack-grep is already the newest version (2.22-1)
```

but ack-grep gives

```
ack-grep: command not found
```

It was working fine in Ubuntu 16.04, before upgrading to 18.04

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ack-grep` is a meta package to pull `ack` in 18.04.

Try to do `sudo apt install ack` and execute `ack` instead of `ack-grep` ; that's a proper command.

Comment: Ok thanks. Ack.vim plugin is still broken, ack-grep: command not found. Any ideas?

Comment: It could be the plugin issue...

Comment: Installing The Silver Seacher fixed it https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher